# Accessing to pivot inside a scope

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I spend nearly one hour on this problem. I have a `User` model and a `Event` model, linked with a ManyToMany relation (representing an invitation system). I made a model for the pivot class :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Invitation extends Pivot
{
    const PENDING = 0;
    const ACCEPTED = 1;
    const UNCERTAIN = 2;
    const REFUSED = 3;
}
```

This is the `User` model :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // Deleted useless things

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event')
                    ->using('App\Invitation')
                    ->withPivot('status')
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

And the `Event` model :

```
class Event extends Model
{
    public function guests()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
                    ->using('App\Invitation')
                    ->withPivot('status')
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }

    /**
     * Return a list of guests who accepted the invitation.
     */
    public function scopeAccepted($query)
    {
        return $query->wherePivot('status', Invitation::ACCEPTED);
    }
}
```

While this statement works nice :
`$event = Event::find(9)->guests()->wherePivot('status', Invitation::ACCEPTED)->get();`

The method `scopeAccepted` give me this error :
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::accepted()` with `$event = Event::find(9)->guests()->accepted()->get();`

Comment: Because you must define `accepted` scope in the returned type of `->guests()` witch is User :)

Comment: I still get an error : ```SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `users`.*, `event_user`.`event_id` as `pivot_event_id`, `event_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `event_user`.`status` as `pivot_status`, `event_user`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `event_user`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `users` inner join `event_user` on `users`.`id` = `event_user`.`user_id` where `event_user`.`event_id` = 9 and `pivot` = status)```

How can I make a function inside Event model that return only users who accepted the invitation ?

Comment: Try this `public function acceptedGuests(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
                    ->using('App\Invitation')
                    ->withPivot('status')
                    ->where('status', '=', Invitation::ACCEPTED);
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }` and call it like this `$event = Event::find(9)->acceptedGuests()->get();` !!

Comment: Yess that's perfect! I improved it a litte : ```public function acceptedGuests()
    {
        return $this->guests()->where('status', '=', Invitation::ACCEPTED);
    }```

Comment: Happy to help :)